# Why we can use train_test_split without an object creation but using linear_models like LinearRegression or StandardScaler() would need an instance

Tags: sklearn-pandas

I am new to Data Science in Python and while importing different libraries I can see they are being used in 2 different ways:

```
`import statsmodels.api as sm  
import sklearn  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression`
```

Even within sklearn train_test_split and StandardScaler are called differently before use

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the source code of Scikit-learn libraries
[(link)](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py)

train_test_split is defined as a quick utility to divide arrays or matrices into random train and test subsets. It does not need much parameters to define its behaviour.

More complex utilities, like StandardScaler() or LinearRegression(), are composed by multiple methods and attributes, they give a more friendly way to the developer to manage the process he is interested into.